# month function is not created error on the denodo server using oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, denodo

I am trying to show the delta for total (current vs previous day) but the month function does not work in oracle. I also use denodo to run this query. I tried to add an extract function to make it work with the month but also does not seem to work fine.

pedics :

```
study id        date         total
RSCLS CA10001  2020-08-11    52
RSCLS CA10001  2020-08-10    52
ETDLD CA20302  2020-08-11    99
ERGKG CA34524  2020-08-11    31
```

Query:

```
select
  tt1.study,
  tt1.id,
  tt1.date,
  tt1.total,
  (tt1.total-ifnull(tt2.total, 0)) as delta
from pedics tt1
  left outer JOIN pedics tt2 on tt1.total = tt2.total
    and month(tt1.date1)-month(tt2.date1)=1;
```

Comment: If you want the previous day, why are you using months?  And because of the `join` condition, `delta` is always going to be `0`.  Presumably, you want the previous value based on the first column, not the last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below - using `extract(month from datecolumn)`

```
select
  tt1.study,
  tt1.id,
  tt1.date,
  tt1.total,
  tt1.total-coalesce(tt2.total, 0) as delta
from pedics tt1
  left outer JOIN pedics tt2 on tt1.total = tt2.total
    and extract(month from tt1.date)-extract(month from tt2.date)=1
```

Comment: Error in join view conditions: Field not found 'tt1.date1' in view 'tt1'

Comment: that's exactly I tried, I got Finished with error: Function 'if null' with arity 2 not found

Comment: @KSp, have you tried using coalesce instead of ifnull

Comment: @KSp . . . Although this technically addresses the question you asked, I don't think it does anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `month()` or `extract()` for this!  It is not going to work in January.  Instead:

```
select tt1.study, tt1.id, tt1.date, tt1.total,
       (tt1.total - coalesce(tt2.total, 0)) as delta
from pedics tt1 left outer join
     pedics tt2
     on tt1.total = tt2.total and
        trunc(tt1.date1, 'MON') = trunc(tt2.date1, 'MON') + interval '1' month;
```

However, your question suggests that you just want the previous row based on the date.  So, I would imagine that you really want:

```
select p.*,
       (p.total - lag(p.total, 1, 0) over (partition by study_id order by date)) as delta
from pedics p;
```